# How to create split view controller like apple mail

Tags: ios, swift

I create a Split View Controller with a master and detail. What I am trying to accomplish is to create my split view controller to be similar to apple mail Where I would have my list of mailboxes, then when I tap on one, it shows a list of messages and if you tap on one of those show the message.

Has anyone seen a tutorial on how to do this? After looking at the mail app on iPhone and iPad, I noticed that it first show the master, on iPad the master gets replace with the list of messages and it looks like on iPad it goes from master to table view, then from the list of messages goes into detail view.

Can someone help me and point me in the right direction on accomplishing what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/265-uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started, https://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Comment: Or create a new application in Xcode  with the “Master-Detail App” template.

Comment: You can use Apple built in template project type `Master Detail App` when you are creating new project.